# Using streams to manipulate then write data to CSV

Tags: mysql, node.js, streaming

I'm writing a script which runs a MySQL query that returns ~5 million results. I need to manipulate this data:

- Formatting
- Encoding
- Convert some sections to JSON
- etc

Then write that to a CSV file in the shortest amount of time possible.

Since the [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) module is able to handle streams, I figured that's my best route. However I'm not familiar enough with writing my own streams to do this.

What would be the best way to stream the data from MySQL, through a formatting function and into a CSV.

We're in a position where we don't mind what order the data goes in as, so long as it's written to a CSV file real quick.

Comment: I guess I'll need some kind of Transform Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv seems to do what you need. It can get streams, write streams, and has built-in transformers.

Comment: Thanks, I used that module and it worked great. The problem is it now takes so long to do everything I need the code to do, so I've pretty much scrapped the idea I had.